# Is it possible to mongodump the last "x" records from a collection?

Tags: mongodb

Can you use mongodump to dump the latest "x" documents from a collection? For example, in the mongo shell you can execute:

```
db.stats.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(10);
```

Is this same capability available to mongodump?

I guess the workaround would be to dump the above documents into a new temporary collection and mongodump the entire temp collection, but would be great to just be able to do this via mongodump.

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: similar requirements, but i want latest n records for each collection to setup dev/test server.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`mongodump` does not fully expose the cursor interfaces.
But you can work around it, using the `--query` parameter.
First get the total number of documents of the collection

```
db.collection.count()
```

Let's say there are 10000 documents and you want the last 1000.
To do so get the id of first document you want to dump.

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id:1}).skip(10000 - 1000).limit(1)
```

In this example the id was `"50ad7bce1a3e927d690385ec"`.
Now you can feed `mongodump` with this information, to dump all documents a with higher or equal id.

```
$ mongodump -d 'your_database' -c 'your_collection' -q '{_id: {$gte: ObjectId("50ad7bce1a3e927d690385ec")}}'
```

**UPDATE**
The new parameters `--limit` and `--skip` were added to `mongoexport` will be probably available in the next version of the tool: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/pull/307

Comment: Very smart answer... nice one!

Comment: `db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).skip(1000).limit(1)` also does the trick and has the bonus you don't need to iterate over all previous records.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.ObjectId if you're on 4.2

Comment: Like @dtc said you need to use `{ "$oid": ... }` instead of `ObjectId(...)`, or you will could get `error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input`.

Answer (score 8):

Building off of Mic92's answer, to get the most recent 1000 items from a collection:

Find the `_id` of the 1000th most recent item:

`db.collection.find('', {'_id':1}).sort({_id:-1}).skip(1000).limit(1)`

It will be something like `50ad7bce1a3e927d690385ec`.

Then pass this _id in a query to mongodump:

`$ mongodump -d 'your_database' -c 'your_collection' -q '{"_id": {"$gt": {"$oid": "50ad7bce1a3e927d690385ec"}}}'`

Comment: Minor fix: this code dumps 1001 records. You can replace $gte with $gt.

Comment: I was getting `Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input`, had to change the query to: `-q '{ "_id": { "$gte": { "$oid": "50ad7bce1a3e927d690385ec" } } }'` - `{ "$oid": ... }` instead of using `ObjectId(...)` directly.

Comment: Good catch @Qtax - it looks like newer versions of mongo have slightly different syntax, so I updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

[mongodump supports the --query operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3aDumpingaSingleCollectionwithaquery).  If you can specify your query as a json query, you should be able to do just that.

If not, then your trick of running a query to dump the records into a temporary collection and then dumping that will work just fine.  In this case, you could automate the dump using a shell script that calls a mongo with a javascript command to do what you want and then calling mongodump.

Comment: right, the mongodump program will allow the query, but not allow you to add a limit.  Thanks for confirming my secondary logic, that's what I ended up doing in the end.

Answer (score 3):

`_id`-based approaches may not work if you use a custom `_id` for your collection (such as returned by a 3rd party API). In that case, you should depend on a `createdAt` or equivalent field:

```sh
COL="collectionName"
HOW_MANY=10000

DATE_CUTOFF=$(mongo <host, user, pass...> dbname --quiet \
--eval "db.$COL.find({}, { createdAt: 1 }).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).skip($HOW_MANY).limit(1)"\
| grep -E -o '(ISODate\(.*?\))')

echo "Copying $HOW_MANY items after $DATE_CUTOFF..."

mongodump <host, user, pass...> -d dbname -c ${COL}\
-q "{ createdAt: { \$gte: $DATE_CUTOFF} }" --gzip
```

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with a similar requirement (using mongodump) where I wanted to do sequential backup and restore. I would take dump from last stored timestamp.
I couldn't get through --query '{ TIMESTAMP : { $gte : $stime, $lt : $etime } }'

Some points to note:
1) use single quote instead of double
2) do not escape $ or anything
3) replacing $stime/$etime with real numbers will make the query work
4) problem I had was with getting $stime/$etime resolved before mongodump executes itself
   under -x it showed as 
+ eval mongodump  --query '{TIMESTAMP:{\$gte:$utc_stime,\$lt:$utc_etime}}'
++ mongodump  --query '{TIMESTAMP:$gte:1366700243}' '{TIMESTAMP:$lt:1366700253}'

Hell, the problem was evident. query gets converted into two conditionals.

The solution is tricky and I got it after repeated trials....
escape { and } ie use { ..} . This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NUM=10000    
doc=selected_doc
taskid=$(mongo 127.0.0.1/selected_db -u username -p password --eval "db.${doc}.find({}, {_id: 1}).sort({_id: -1}).skip($NUM).limit(1)" |  grep -E  -o '"[0-9a-f]+"')
mongodump --collection $doc  --db selected_db --host 127.0.0.1 -u username -p password -q "{_id: {\$gte: $taskid}}" --out ${doc}.dump
```

Comment: The `mongo` line can be improved by passing `quiet` in order to silence various mongo warnings (different shell versions etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Strategy is simple but there are some challenges to doing that. I am assuming we are using `_id` field to do that. And we know `_id` field is incremental thus it is a good indicator to find recent documents.

1. Find X'th record accordingly in the collection
2. Extract the `_id` field of document
3. Use the `_id` field in `mongodump --query`

### Find X'th record accordingly in the collection

We can achive that by using `--eval` with `mongo` tool.

- Sort the documents newest to oldest
- limit X record reverse sort it
- take the first document (limit:1)
- stringify Id

```
mongo --host=$mongodb_uri --quiet --eval db.myCollection.aggregate([{\$sort:{_id:-1}},{\$limit:$MAX_DOCUMENT},{\$sort:{_id:1}},{\$limit:1},{\$project:{_id:{\$toString:\"\$_id\"}}}])
```

result=`{ "_id" : "62440d84c18a957093f6c8a3" }`

### Extract the _id field of document

We need the exact value of _id so we do some regex

```
$(echo $result | sed -e 's/{ "_id" : "\(.*\)" }/\1/')
```

lastId=`62440d84c18a957093f6c8a3`

### Use the `_id` field in `mongodump --query`

mongodump does not accept ObjectId so we should use `$oid` to indicate ObjectId fields.

`query="{\"_id\":{\"\$gte\":{\"\$oid\":\"$lastId\"}}}"`

Here is the complete bash script

```bash
dump()
{
    local lastIdQuery="db.$collection.aggregate([{\$sort:{_id:-1}},{\$limit:$MAX_DOCUMENT},{\$sort:{_id:1}},{\$limit:1},{\$project:{_id:{\$toString:\"\$_id\"}}}])"
    echo "lastIdQuery $lastIdQuery"
    local lastIdResult=$(mongo --host=$mongodb_uri --quiet --eval "$lastIdQuery")
    echo "lastIdResult $lastIdResult"
    local lastId=$(echo $lastIdResult | sed -e 's/{ "_id" : "\(.*\)" }/\1/')
    echo $lastId
    query="{\"_id\":{\"\$gte\":{\"\$oid\":\"$lastId\"}}}"
    echo "query $query"
    mongodump --uri=$mongodb_uri   --collection $collection --query="$query" --out=$outFolder
}


mongodb_uri='mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb'
outFolder=./backup
MAX_DOCUMENT=100
collection="users"

dump
```