# mongodb pymongo dump range of documents and then delete and ensure that non-dumped are not deleted

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In a mongodb database that could be updated at any time, I want to dump the records over a given range and then delete the dumped records. Since the db could be updated during the dump process, how can I be sure that using the same range to filter the deletions will not end up deleting a document that was loaded during the dump?

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828817/is-it-possible-to-mongodump-the-last-x-records-from-a-collection) q/a to help (the top answer), except I'm using pymongo and I need the assurance that I'm not deleting anything not dumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that more documents might have been added, so the simplest answer is "don't use the same range".

As you retrieve the documents in the dump, keep a list of the _id values and then submit a delete using `_id:{$in:[values seen in the dump]}`